# setTimeout and setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to call the function `work()` every 6 seconds.  My jQuery code is

```
function looper(){
  // do something
  if (loopcheck) {           
    setInterval(work,6000);
    }
  else {
    console.log('looper stopped');
  }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that it loops over work twice quickly, and then it will wait for 6 seconds.  i tried using `setTimeout` with similar results.

What could be causing work to be called twice before the delay works?

Comment: show full js code and when you call looper. Maybe this function is called twice

Comment: You're certain work isn't being called elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

setInterval [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479762/will-setinterval-cause-browsers-to-hang).  If you want work to be repeatedly called every 6 seconds, consider a recursive call to setTimeout instead

```
function loopWork(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        work();
        loopWork();
    }, 6000);
}
```

Then

```
function looper(){
  // do something
  if (loopcheck) {           
    loopWork()
  }
  else {
    console.log('looper stopped');
  }
}
```

And of course if you ever want to stop this, you'd save the value of the last call to setTimeout, and pass that to clearTimeout

```
var timeoutId;
timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    work();
    loopWork();
}, 6000);
```

Then to stop it

```
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Comment: Noting of course that this doesn't run the function every six seconds, it runs the function and then schedules the next one for six seconds later - so if the function takes one second to run it will run every seven seconds. (Of course most _sensible_ JS code doesn't take a whole second to run, but still...)

Answer (score 0):

Use old-style setTimeout()

```
        var i=0;
        function work(){
            console.log(i++);
        }
        function runner(){
            work();
            setTimeout(runner, 6000);
        }            
        runner();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following pattern myself I find it easier to follow:

```
function LoopingFunction() {
    // do the work

    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 6000); // call myself again in 6 seconds
}
```

And if you want to be able to stop it at any point:

```
var LoopingFunctionKeepGoing = true;
function LoopingFunction() {
    if(!LoopingFunctionKeepGoing) return;
    // do the work

    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 6000); // call myself again in 6 seconds
}
```

Now you can stop it at any time by setting LoopingFunctionKeepGoing to false.