# HighStock chart get hange browser when new data fill at 10sec interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will setInterval cause browsers to hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479762/will-setinterval-cause-browsers-to-hang)

i implement Highstock JS v1.1.4 chart for represent data

chart code  :

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'highchartviewpanel',
        events:{

            load:function(){
                setIntervalForhighchartdata();
            }
            }

    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        },{
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        },
        {
            count: 15,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '15M'
        }],
        selected:0,
        inputEnabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
    height: 40,
    xAxis: {

     valueDecimals: 1
       }
     },

    title: {
        text: 'payment analysis',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: -20,
        top: 20
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second : '%H:%M:%S',
            minute : '%H:%M',
            hour: '%H',
            day : '%b,%d',
            week : 'b,%d',
            month : '%Y,%b',
            year : '%Y'
        },
    valueDecimals: 0
    },
    yAxis: [
    {
        title: {
            text: 'item1'
        },
        height: 50,
        lineWidth: 2
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'item2'
        },
        top: 90,
        height: 50,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    },{
        title: {
            text: 'item3'
        },
        top: 150,
        height: 50,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],
    series: [{
        name: 'item1',
        data: item1data,
        color:'blue'
       }, 
       {
        name: 'item2',
         yAxis: 1,
        data: item2data,
        color:'black'

    },{         
        name: 'item3',
        yAxis: 2,
        data: item3data,
        color:'red'

    }]
});
```

}

setIntervalForhighchartdata() is function which update graph every 10 sec and my data value is base on time interval xdata is datetime and ydata is data point of 1,2,3 ....

its hang browser some time  when graph update

Answer (score 1):

The function your calling probably doesn't complete itself before you call it again.I assume you're using `setInterval()`. If so, I'd suggest using it combined with `setTimeout()`.

For more info check out this thread - [Will setInterval cause browsers to hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479762/will-setinterval-cause-browsers-to-hang)

Comment: i try with both method setInterval() and setTimeout() then also its hang browser