# Can anyone provide a simple fading slideshow jquery script for a noob?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, transition

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make a simple slideshow? My current one is choppy, and Im just looking for it to simply fade to the next image.

I am using the below code to autoplay my slideshow on [my homepage](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com) and the css for the fade. The fade starts off very jerky/choppy. Im not sure what is causing this.

```
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.setInterval(slideClick, 5000);

    function slideClick() {
     $(".slide").click();
    }
    </script>
```

---

```
.slide {    
-webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;}
```

Comment: Wheres the rest of your slider `JS` code?

Comment: Have you tried pre-loading the images?

Answer (score 0):

Try "*[pre-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476681/1298685)*" the images first, for more immediate image manipulation:

```
// this variable is used in both code-snippets:
var images = $("img");

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $("<img/>")[0].src = this;
    });
}

preload($("img"));
```

...and then you could transition the images with javascript's `setTimeout` and jQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` :

```
var currentIndex = images.length;
var delay = 4000;

(function transitionImages() {
    // fading the current image out:
    images.eq(currentIndex).fadeOut(delay);

    var previousIndex = currentIndex;
    while (currentIndex == previousIndex) {
        // setting a new unique index here:
        currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    }

    // fading the next image in:
    images.eq(currentIndex).fadeIn(delay / 2);

    // recursive timeout here:
    setTimeout(transitionImages, delay);
})(); // end of immediately-invoked function expression ("IIFE")
```

I'm having some trouble getting it to start exactly on page load, but I think it's because my images are too large ha, so be sure to try it with smaller images.

Try experimenting with having different delay times for `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, but be aware that it will sometimes lead to glitchy image rendering.

Also, [here's a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5479821/1298685) that explains why `setTimeout` is preferable to `setInterval`.

*UPDATE*:

Also it would seem that pre-loading the images should be done at the end of the `<head>` section, but alas I am still having jQuery response-time problems when trying this animation with large and/or numerous images...